# Generate floating point random number with E=0

Tags: c++, random

`uniform_real_distribution` does not include the right end. This means that it is not possible right a way to generate random numbers with E=0. How can I create a `uniform_real_distribution` with either an open interval, or a closed interval, not half-open?

One could argue that the bias towards negative values does not matter, because the difference is small, but still, it is not fully correct.

Comment: @mkluwe It's even mentioned in the [relevant docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution) so you need not know every floating point facility by heart.

Comment: @mkluwe How could I miss that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) with [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter):

```
template <typename RealType = double>
auto make_closed_real_distribution(RealType a = 0.0, RealType b = 1.0) {
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType>(
        a, std::nextafter(b, std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()));
}
```

After a bit of lookup, this is actually the method proposed on [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/uniform_real_distribution).

If you want to make an open-interval, simply use `nextafter()` on the first argument:

```
template <typename RealType = double>
auto make_open_real_distribution(RealType a = 0.0, RealType b = 1.0) {
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType>(
        std::nextafter(a, std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()), b);
}
```

Comment: Now *that's* a clever trick, and a nice way of showing the interesting properties of floating point numbers.

Comment: In your second example, shouldn't that be `std::numeric_limits<RealType>::max()` as well ?

Comment: @Quentin It should since  you want to exclude the lower bound, answer updated, thanks.